# Number grid using arrays or classes in processing (java) coding

Tags: java, arrays, class, coding-style, processing

Using processing I am trying to recreate snakes and ladders games. The grid is done and so is a "dice".

i would like to number the grid like the actual snakes and ladders games. And also add a way that when I move the pawn there will be a link between the "dice" (number that is shown at the bottom of the screen) and the number of boxes the pawn will move.

```
   // Class that displays a single cell of a checker board
class GameBoard {
  /*-----------------------properties------------------*/
  float x;
  float y;
  int rVal;
  int gVal;
  int bVal;
  color squareColor; //color of cell fill
  int ccSize; //size of cell


  /*-----------------------methods---------------------*/
  // constructor method
  public GameBoard(int tempX, int tempY, color tempColor, int tempSize) {
    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    squareColor = tempColor; 
    ccSize = tempSize;
  }

  // draws    ccColor = tempColor; the cell. This is public because other objects will need to 
  // be able to tell the object to draw itself.
  public void display() {
    fill(squareColor);
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CORNER);
    rect(x, y, ccSize, ccSize);
  }
}

class Dice {  
  float xDice;
  float yDice;
  float diceSize;
  String randomNumber = "";

  public Dice (float xNewDice, float yNewDice, float newDiceSize) {
    xDice = xNewDice;
    yDice = yNewDice;
    diceSize = newDiceSize;
    randomNumber = "4";
  }
  public void displayDice() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(255);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(xDice, yDice, diceSize, diceSize);
  }

  public void displayNumber() {

    textSize(50); 
    fill(0);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    text(randomNumber, xDice, yDice);
  }
  public void getRandomNumber() {
    float referenceNumber = int(random(1, 7));

    if (referenceNumber == 1) {
      randomNumber = "1";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 2) {
      randomNumber = "2";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 3) {
      randomNumber = "3";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 4) {
      randomNumber = "4";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 5) {
      randomNumber = "5";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 6) {
      randomNumber = "6";
    }
  }

  public void generateRandom() {

    textSize(50); 
    fill(0);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    text(randomNumber, xDice, yDice);

    float referenceNumber = int(random(1, 7));

    if (referenceNumber == 1) {
      randomNumber = "1";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 2) {
      randomNumber = "2";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 3) {
      randomNumber = "3";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 4) {
      randomNumber = "4";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 5) {
      randomNumber = "5";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 6) {
      randomNumber = "6";
    }
  }
}


boolean rollingDice = false;

//create an array of GameBoard objects
GameBoard[] [] squareBoard;
Dice randomDice;
//number of GameBoards
int cellSize = 100;



// set things up
void setup() {
   noStroke();
  size(700, 800);
  background(0);
  //initialize the array of GameBoard objects
  //base it on the size of the canvas and the size of the individual cells
  squareBoard = new GameBoard[width/cellSize][height/cellSize];
  randomDice = new Dice (width/2, 750, 80);
  //initialize checker board
  initCheckerboard();
}

// main drawing loop
void draw() {
  background(44, 44, 44);
  drawCheckerboard();
  randomDice.displayDice();
  randomDice.displayNumber();
  if(rollingDice) {
    randomDice.generateRandom();
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  rollingDice = !rollingDice;
}

// draws a checkerboard pattern 
void initCheckerboard() {
  // flag to indicate whether to fill with white or black
  boolean white = true; 
  GameBoard cCell;

  // flag to indicate whether we are starting an odd or even column
  // this is used to ensure that column n + 1 always starts with a different fill
  // than column n.
  boolean oddColumn = true;

  // walk across the x-axis
  for (int x=0; x < width; x = x+cellSize) {
    // walk down the y-axis
    for (int y=0; y < height-100; y = y+cellSize) {
      // create the GameBoard
      if (white) {
        cCell = new GameBoard(x, y, color(64, 64, 64), cellSize);
      } 
      else {
        cCell = new GameBoard(x, y, color(44, 44, 44), cellSize);
      }
      squareBoard[x/cellSize][y/cellSize] = cCell;
      //invert the fill color for next cell
      white = !white;
    }

    // make sure that each successive column starts with a different fill
    white = !oddColumn;

    // flip the flag that tells us whether we're starting an even or odd column
    oddColumn = !oddColumn;
  }
}

// draws a checkerboard pattern 
void drawCheckerboard() {
   noStroke();
  // walk across the x-axis
  for (int x=0; x < width; x = x+cellSize) {
    // walk down the y-axis
    for (int y=0; y < height-100; y = y+cellSize) {
      // draw the GameBoard
      squareBoard[x/cellSize][y/cellSize].display();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, a side note I suppose would be that *if* you were really dead set on all those `if`s they should be `else if`s, but isn't there a way to go straight to a String in Java?

Comment: @BobbyDigital [Integer.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: @JoséM.Benítez: I know :) I was hinting about.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Sorry, my mistake! O:)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change your code as little as possible. As for the movement and the dice, that is a different subject and you have no code in there to do it... I would suggest trying a few things first and if you can't get it ask another question!

As for the numbers as in the snake game you need to fill the rows first, start from below, and every row switch the x of the check rectangles:

```
// Class that displays a single cell of a checker board
class GameBoard {
  /*-----------------------properties------------------*/
  float x;
  float y;
  int rVal;
  int gVal;
  int bVal;
  color squareColor; //color of cell fill
  int ccSize; //size of cell
  int index;


  /*-----------------------methods---------------------*/
  // constructor method
  public GameBoard(int tempX, int tempY, color tempColor, int tempSize, int i) {
    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    squareColor = tempColor; 
    ccSize = tempSize;
    index = i;
  }

  // draws    ccColor = tempColor; the cell. This is public because other objects will need to 
  // be able to tell the object to draw itself.
  public void display() {
    fill(squareColor);
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CORNER);
    rect(x, y, ccSize, ccSize);
    fill(255);
    text(String.valueOf(index), x-ccSize*0.5, y-ccSize*0.5, 200, 200);
  }
}

class Dice {  
  float xDice;
  float yDice;
  float diceSize;
  String randomNumber = "";

  public Dice (float xNewDice, float yNewDice, float newDiceSize) {
    xDice = xNewDice;
    yDice = yNewDice;
    diceSize = newDiceSize;
    randomNumber = "4";
  }
  public void displayDice() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(255);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(xDice, yDice, diceSize, diceSize);
  }

  public void displayNumber() {

    textSize(50); 
    fill(0);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    text(randomNumber, xDice, yDice);
  }
  public void getRandomNumber() {
    float referenceNumber = int(random(1, 7));

    if (referenceNumber == 1) {
      randomNumber = "1";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 2) {
      randomNumber = "2";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 3) {
      randomNumber = "3";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 4) {
      randomNumber = "4";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 5) {
      randomNumber = "5";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 6) {
      randomNumber = "6";
    }
  }

  public void generateRandom() {

    textSize(50); 
    fill(0);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    text(randomNumber, xDice, yDice);

    float referenceNumber = int(random(1, 7));

    if (referenceNumber == 1) {
      randomNumber = "1";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 2) {
      randomNumber = "2";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 3) {
      randomNumber = "3";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 4) {
      randomNumber = "4";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 5) {
      randomNumber = "5";
    }

    if (referenceNumber == 6) {
      randomNumber = "6";
    }
  }
}


boolean rollingDice = false;

//create an array of GameBoard objects
GameBoard[] [] squareBoard;
Dice randomDice;
//number of GameBoards
int cellSize = 100;



// set things up
void setup() {
  noStroke();
  size(700, 800);
  background(0);
  //initialize the array of GameBoard objects
  //base it on the size of the canvas and the size of the individual cells
  squareBoard = new GameBoard[width/cellSize][height/cellSize];
  randomDice = new Dice (width/2, 750, 80);
  //initialize checker board
  initCheckerboard();
}

// main drawing loop
void draw() {
  background(44, 44, 44);
  drawCheckerboard();
  randomDice.displayDice();
  randomDice.displayNumber();
  if (rollingDice) {
    randomDice.generateRandom();
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  rollingDice = !rollingDice;
}

// draws a checkerboard pattern 
void initCheckerboard() {
  // flag to indicate whether to fill with white or black
  boolean white = true; 
  GameBoard cCell;

  // flag to indicate whether we are starting an odd or even column
  // this is used to ensure that column n + 1 always starts with a different fill
  // than column n.
  boolean oddColumn = true;
  int index = 0;
  boolean switcher = false;
  // walk down the y-axis
  for (int y=height-100-cellSize; y >= 0 ; y = y-cellSize) {
    // walk across the x-axis
    for (int x=0; x < width; x = x+cellSize) {
      // create the GameBoard
      int nx = x;
      if(switcher) nx = width - cellSize - x;
      if (white) {
        cCell = new GameBoard(nx, y, color(64, 64, 64), cellSize, index);
      } 
      else {
        cCell = new GameBoard(nx, y, color(44, 44, 44), cellSize, index);
      }
      println(y);
      squareBoard[x/cellSize][y/cellSize] = cCell;
      //invert the fill color for next cell
      white = !white;
      index++;
    }
    switcher = !switcher;

    // make sure that each successive column starts with a different fill
    white = !oddColumn;

    // flip the flag that tells us whether we're starting an even or odd column
    oddColumn = !oddColumn;
  }
}

// draws a checkerboard pattern 
void drawCheckerboard() {
  noStroke();
  // walk across the x-axis
  for (int x=0; x < width; x = x+cellSize) {
    // walk down the y-axis
    for (int y=0; y < height-100; y = y+cellSize) {
      // draw the GameBoard
      squareBoard[x/cellSize][y/cellSize].display();
    }
  }
}
```